# Raster Calculator Blurred Resolution

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, spatial-analyst, raster-calculator, interpolation

I am attempting to add two rasters in Raster Calculator, but I am getting a blurred image that is not anywhere close to the original two rasters placed into the calculator.

Dimensions of the input rasters are identical and are the following: 
X Size: 0.0083
Y Size: 0.0083
Columns: 7322 x 4142

The initial result from the calculation is at a lower resolution from an image that was calculated earlier in ArcMap. I've attached each input raster and the output raster:

**Input Raster 1** [image: Input Raster 1] **Input Raster 2** [image: Input Raster 2] **Computed Raster** [image: Computed Raster] **Calculation** [image]

Comment: Open the output layer properties and in the Display tab, change the resampling from bilinear to nearest.

Answer (score 1):

It may depend on the version of ArcGIS you are using.  I have had similar issues working with rasters in 10.3. when using multiple Spatial Analyst functions if my input and output locations were set to a geodatabase. Try moving the inputs to a folder and changing the output to a regular folder to see if that makes a difference.

Comment: Excellent idea! The majority of my data is stashed in my default geodatabase, so at first blush it wouldn't surprise me if your expectation is correct. I'll be trying that soon, I'll post further on this if it does work.